# What is the use of .container div in this W3Schools example?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I was trying to learn about [CSS layout horizontal alignment](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) and came across [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_pos_crossbrowser) example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #b0e0e6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">
    <p><b>Note: </b>When aligning using the position property, always include the !DOCTYPE declaration! If missing, it can produce strange results in IE browsers.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If we remove `.container` class or the entire `div.container`, the effect is **none** on [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/), [IE 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_10) and [IE 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8)

What is the role of this .container in this example?

Comment: It is what it says ...  some say "wrapper" ..  it's for easier control of elements inside.  I agree, if you have a single element, with the class `right`, it seems like it doesn't need to be there .. but lets say you want the entire page to take up `80%` of display width, and THEN float your child element `right`  --  A container is the easiest method to accomplish this.  So it's not needed in your example per-se .. But it is ;-)

Comment: @Zak A fiddle may help better understand!!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wy42gx27/6/ -- edited

Comment: Ah. the perils of following w3schools examples.... Formally, it has no effect because the right content box edge of the `.container` element is coincident with the right edge of the initial containing block. But don't expect w3schools to explain that (or even understand it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is what it says A "container"  ... some say "wrapper" .. it's for easier control of elements inside. I agree, if you have a single element, with the class right, it seems like it doesn't need to be there .. but lets say you want the entire page to take up 80% of display width, and THEN float your child element right -- A container is the easiest method to accomplish this. So it's not needed in your example per-se .. But it is ;-)

```
.container {
position: relative;
border: 1px #00FF00 solid;
width: 80%;
height:500px;
}

.right {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
background-color: #b0e0e6;
border: 1px #FF0000 solid;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wy42gx27/6)

Comment: So, the role of `div.container` is not allowing `div.right` to go out of `div.container`, Is that the whole point? Also without `position: absolute;`, the `div.right` sticks to the left edge.

Comment: correct .. and .. correct..  It will stick to the left edge because the surrounding `DIV` is `relative` ... and `absolute` has nothing to base it's "absoluteness" on without a `relative` div surrounding it.  I suggest you read more about `relative`, `absolute`, and `floating` ..